# Android JSON Parsing issue-java.lang.string cannot be converted to JSONObject

Tags: android, json

I am using the following code to parse JSON in android application

```
    JSONArray category = null;
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    JSONObject json = jParser
            .getJSONFromUrl("http://www.inchid.com/mobile/cate.php?cType=Product");

    try {

        category = json.getJSONArray("cate");


        for (int i = 0; i < category.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = category.getJSONObject(i);

            String name = c.getString("cate_name");

        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {

        // TODO: handle exception
        System.out.println("ERRRORRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR");

    }
```

**JSONParser class**

```
  public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();          

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
```

This makes my application to force close and below picture is the screen shot of logcat.
[image]

Logcat Error is:

**Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value ï»¿ of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some times what happen when you are fetching data from the server at that time some un-wanted characters was added when you compose the String. So try this it will help you.

Instead of return only json object change from

```
return jObj;
```

to

```
return new JSONObject(json.substring(json.indexOf("{"), json.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

Also remove hidden characters on source String.