# JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject in java

Tags: java, android, json

I want to get an json object from this string coming from this JSON file:

```
{
"categories": {
    "category": [
        {
            "label": "Collaboration",
            "thumbnail": "http://mywebite.com/dfsv",
            "description": "...",
            "contents": {
                "@attributes": {
                    "count": "79"
                }
            },
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "ZSQYN2"
            }
        },
        {
            "label": "Communication",
            "thumbnail": "http://mywebite.com/dfsv",
            "description": "...",
            "contents": {
                "@attributes": {
                    "count": "43"
                }
            },
            "@attributes": {
                "id": "uGQ9MC"
            }
        }
    ],
    "@attributes": {
        "page": "12",
        "limit": "0",
        "count": "111",
        "lang": "en"
    }
}
```

}

I'm using this code :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myString);
```

And I got this error message:

> Value ... of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject

And if I do :

```
JSONArray obj = new JSONArray(myString);
```

I got this error message:

> Value ... of type org.json.JSONObject cannot be converted to JSONArray

...

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Are you sure myString is identical in both cases?

Comment: Yes it's the same string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution!

I replaced

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myString);
```

by :

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(myString.substring(myString.indexOf("{"), myString.lastIndexOf("}") + 1));
```

Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21347908/3411154)

Hope it will help someone!

Answer (score 1):

`JSONArray` and `JSONObject` are two different things, and should not be type compatible with one another, so these errors make sense.   This is a JSONArray:

`["foo", "bar", "baz"]`

This is a JSONObject:

`{ "foo" : "bar", "baz" : "quux" }`

You may be looking for `JSONElement`, which in APIs like [Google's GSON](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html) is the common superclass between both arrays and objects.

Under the Android [JSON API](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) they're also not type compatible.